# clinfo.exe crash with an error

Tags: opencl, amd-gpu, codexl

```
Now I installed the AMD APP SDK 3.0 and try to check if it is installed successfully.When I use cmd and clinfo command, it displays information but with an error terminated finally.It makes me confused. The picture as follows.
```

[The clinfo.exe error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCQ0Z.png) 
    I don't know how to solve with it. Before I run the command clinfo, I can use CodeXL Teapot sample and debug and analysis it. After I run the clinfo command, CodeXL Teapot sample also crashed. When I unistall AMD APP SDK 3.0, the clinfo command has no error and CodeXL is also recovered.
    My system is windows 10 X64, GPU is AMD FirePro W7100,AMD APP SDK is X64.
Who can give me some advice?